# Why does code write this way the method indexOf() in String.class?

Tags: java, string, indexof

I'm reading the source code of `String.class`.
In the method `indexOf()` I see something I can't understand.
Here is the method `indexOf()` code snippet from `String.class` source code.

```
/**
 * Code shared by String and StringBuffer to do searches. The
 * source is the character array being searched, and the target
 * is the string being searched for.
 *
 * @param   source       the characters being searched.
 * @param   sourceOffset offset of the source string.
 * @param   sourceCount  count of the source string.
 * @param   target       the characters being searched for.
 * @param   targetOffset offset of the target string.
 * @param   targetCount  count of the target string.
 * @param   fromIndex    the index to begin searching from.
 */
static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount,
        char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount,
        int fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
        return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
    }
    if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    }
    if (targetCount == 0) {
        return fromIndex;
    }

    char first = target[targetOffset];
    int max = sourceOffset + (sourceCount - targetCount);

    for (int i = sourceOffset + fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
        /* Look for first character. */
        if (source[i] != first) {
            while (++i <= max && source[i] != first);
        }

        /* Found first character, now look at the rest of v2 */
        if (i <= max) {
            int j = i + 1;
            int end = j + targetCount - 1;
            for (int k = targetOffset + 1; j < end && source[j]
                    == target[k]; j++, k++);

            if (j == end) {
                /* Found whole string. */
                return i - sourceOffset;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I can't understand the code here.

```
if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
    return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
}
```

If the `source String` is `"abcdedefg"`, `sourceOffset` is `2`, `sourceCount` is `3`, 
and I want to search "d" from this,
why can't I search from index 4?
/**
* Ps:If the `sourceCount` means the length of the whole string, why not use `source.length` 
 
* instead ?   
*/

Comment: Don't post *pictures* of code, post **code**. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted an image of code and/or errors, rather than the text itself.  Images are harder for everyone to use, including volunteers and future visitors.  If you remove the image and replace it with the relevant text, I will consider retracting my downvote.  See: [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know this. I'm modifying.

Comment: We have no idea what lines are "1756 to 1758"

Comment: @JimGarrison there was a criticized picture, that _did_ show the line numbers for this purpose; the OP now entirely corrected the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method accepts two character arrays - the `source` array is the one being searched and the `target` array is the one being searched for.

However, the offset and count variables limit the search to a sub-array of the `source` and a sub-array of the `target`.

Basically you are searching in the sub-array from `source[sourceOffSet]` to `source[sourceOffset+sourceCount-1]` for the `String` comprised of the characters in the sub-array from `target[targetOffSet]` to `target[targetOffset+targetCount-1]`.

Here's an illustration. The relevant arrays for the search are the sub-arrays:

```
source array : |--------------------|
sub array    :       |-------|        
                   source  source
                   offset  offset +
                           source
                           count - 1

target array : |--------------------|
sub array    :       |-------|        
                   target  target
                   offset  offset +
                           target
                           count - 1
```

However, the search is further limited by supplying `fromIndex`. You start the search from the `fromIndex`'th index of the `source` sub-array.

Since the length of the `source` sub-array is `sourceCount`, if `fromIndex >= sourceCount`, the `target` sub-array cannot be found, so unless the `target` sub-array is empty (i.e. `targetCount == 0`), `-1` is returned.

Let's consider your example:

```
source : "abcdedefg"
sourceOffset : 2
sourceCount : 3
target : "d"
targetOffset : 0
targetCount : 1
fromIndex : 4
```

These parameters mean you are searching in the source sub-string `"cde"` for the target sub-string `"d"` starting from index `4`. However, there is no index `4` in `"cde"`, so `-1` is returned.

Regarding your

> Ps:If the sourceCount means the length of the whole string, why not use source.length instead

As I explained `sourceCount` doesn't mean the length of the whole `source` array, just the length of the sub-array being searched.

Note that when you call `someString.indexOf(str,fromIndex)`, the `static` method you asked about is being called with the following parameters:

```
public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) {
    return indexOf(value, 0, value.length,
            str.value, 0, str.value.length, fromIndex);
}
```

In this case `sourceCount` is equal to `source.length` (i.e. the entire `source` array is being searched starting at `fromIndex`).

Comment: Thanks. So the fromIndex is starting from the offset character, it's not the index of the whole string but the index of this substring ,from 0 ~~ "cde" has  relative index 0,1,2 . Is that so?

Comment: @Saber that's correct. You can also see that from the for loop starting at `int i = sourceOffset + fromIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
        return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
    }
```

This says that in the search index (`fromIndex`) is after the end, string length (`sourceCount`), then return `-1` (not found) unless the sought string is `""` - which is "always found." Quite specific.

Comment: sourceCount means the end of the string? I thought it was the end of a  substring.

Comment: Indeed, the javadoc above is a bit ambiguous: `source       the characters being searched.` could mean both, but `target       the characters being searched for.` makes it clear that source is the large string, and target the search key. They should have used "sought key" or such.